# Copy data from one Form and paste it to mutiple Forms using jQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have form1 which contains number of input fields (text, select, radion and textarea ). At end of the there button called copy. When user clicks on it , it copys data from all fields of the form1.

I have another three to four forms in different pages which contains input fields with same name of form1. At the end each form there is button called populate. When user clicks on populate button data in form1 fields need to filled in the respective form fields.

Comment: all those form are on same page..??if not its not possible with out storing a form values on database.

Comment: @YashPatel you are mostly correct. If you are using ASP or PHP you can save them in a Session variable. Otherwise you would have to use a database, or maybe a cookie (I'm not sure if, or how, that's possible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are willing to limit yourself to HTML 5 compatible browsers, you can use the DOM storage mechanism to save your data and then populate it on the following pages:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/11/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/

You might try using sessionStorage first to see if that meets your needs, since it clears after the browser session ends. Note that DOM Storage only accepts strings, so you need to stringify objects before saving them:

```
var obj = { somekey: 'someValue' };
//store an item
sessionStorage.setItem( 'obj', JSON.stringify( obj ) );

//now get it back out somewhere else
var obj = JSON.parse( sessionStorage.getItem( 'obj' ) );
```